# Count Multiples

Tags: java, count

I have been assigned to write a java program for class that counts multiples. The program takes three integers as input: low, high, x. The program then outputs the number of multiples of x between low and high exclusively.

If the input is: 1, 10, 2

the output would be: 5

My teacher has the proclivity to assign problems we haven't covered in class and I am unsure where to begin. Im not asking for the full code, just how to set up the problem

I am unsure of how to follow my logic thru the program: what I have so far is this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      int low, high, x;
      int count = 0;
      
      low = scnr.nextInt();
      high = scnr.nextInt();
      x = scnr.nextInt();
      
      for(int i = low; i <= high; i++){
         
         if(i % x == 0){
            count++;
         }
         
         if (i % x != 0){
            
            //System.out.println(count);// someone suggested to move this
         }
      }
      System.out.println(count);  
   }
}
~~~~~~

If I input 1, 10, 2

My output is 01234

Moved the print of count outside of the loop... man I am tired.

FINAL EDIT: This code works, it accomplishes the goal. Thank you to @charisma and everyone else that helped me understand what was going on here. I am new to java but determined to learn more! Thanks all!!!!!
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Did you e.g. write `<=` instead of `==`?

Comment: You probably want to print the value of `count` only after the loop (the final count).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you for the missing piece... how dumb of me to leave the print within the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can input numbers using scanner class similar to the following code from w3schools:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
    System.out.println("Enter username");

    String userName = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input
    System.out.println("Username is: " + userName);  // Output user input
  }
}
```

`low`, `high` and `x` can be of data type `int`.

To check which numbers between `low` and `high` are multiples of `x`, you can use a `for` loop. You can declare a new variable `count` that can be incremented using `count++` every time the `for` loop finds a multiple. The `%` operator could be useful to find multiples.

You can output using `System.out.println(" " + );`

**Edit:**

`%` operator requires 2 operands and gives the remainder. So if `i % x == 0`, it means `i` is a multiple of `x`, and we do `count++`.

The value of `i` will run through `low` to `high`.

```
for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    if (i % x == 0) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: im not sure how to use the % operator within the for loop.

for ( i = 0; i % != 0; i++) { 

is that close?

Comment: The modulus operator requires 2 operands and gives remainder. 
For eg. 5 % 2 = 1. Please check my edit.

Comment: We increment count (count++) where you have put question marks. Please check my post for how to use for loop and modulus operator syntax.

Comment: You dont need to break the loop if i is not a multiple. For eg, it needs to check through 1 to 10 if the numbers are multiples of 2, not stop at 1 because it is not a multiple.

Comment: ok, thank you so much, I believe im starting to understand what is actually happening within the loops but my syntax is all wrong

Comment: Also take care of the case where x = 0 to avoid the arithmetic exceptions

Comment: i dont think the variable count is actually counting?

Comment: wait, I am almost there, my code now displays for input: 1 10 2

output: 01234.. So i think I need the sum of count?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get to the basic implementation (as explained by Charisma), you'll notice, that it can take a lot of time if the numbers are huge: you have `high - low + 1` iterations of the loop. Therefore you can start optimizing, to get a result in constant time:

- the first multiple is `qLow * x`, where `qLow` is the [ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the rational quotient `((double) low) / x`,
- the last multiple is `qHigh * x`, where `qHigh` is the floor of the rational quotient `((double) high) / x`,

Java provides a `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()`, but you can get the same result using integer division and playing with the signs:

```java
final int qLow = -(-low / x);
final int qHigh = high / x;
```

Now you just have to count the number of integers between `qLow` and `qHigh` inclusive.

```java
return qHigh - qLow + 1;
```

**Attention**: if `x < 0`, then you need to use `qLow - qHigh`, so it is safer to use:

```java
return x > 0 ? qHigh - qLow + 1 : qLow - qHigh + 1;
```

The case `x == 0` should be dealt with at the beginning.

Comment: this is insightful stuff, thank you for the input

Answer (score -1):

put count++; after the last print statement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).